# Can’t remove glass globe to change bulb

Tags: lighting

The globes on this fixture are somehow secured to the base of the arm and don’t just slide up. This fixture was installed about 2018 and I suspect there might have been a tool of some sort to remove it?[image]

[image]

Comment: Should be an attachment to hold the glass in place.  Maybe a twist and lock, or a clip.  I doubt very much if they just on there by weight.

Comment: I would just grip the bulb at the top using two or three fingers, looks like enough room and done similar before.

Comment: Is it an LED fixture?  How hot does it get when running?